# How to simply connect horizontally stacked modules to a digital bus AND mains?

Tags: connector, components, mains, power-connector

I'm looking for a safe and simple (also, cheap) way to connect a number of modular devices directly next to each other that share a digital bus and also need mains power (230V 50Hz here).

These devices are cheap, simple and small: BOM cost excluding the parts for connecting them is less than €8 in qty 1000; they typically control 2-3 IOs in specific ways; and ​they are not bigger than 1 DIN module.

Mains power would be quite low current. (Definitely not more than 6A on any one pin.) Digital would be 5VDC, GND, 1-Wire (i.e. 0..5V, <16 Kbps).

I would like the assembly of the stack be extremely simple. The method used for connecting them should provide some minimal rigidity for the duration of installation.

I have explored many solutions but have not come to a conclusion:

- Pin-and-socket: My current best bet is putting pins on the "in" side of the devices, sockets on the "out" side, and a blind plug at the end, such that live mains is not exposed under operation.
  However, I have not found any off-the-shelf solutions specifically aimed at my problem.
  There exist some that are specified for up to 600V 7A and a pin spacing of 3,96 mm; however I'm not sure about the compliance of such a solution with EU electrical codes when used as an external interface. Maybe using two pairs of connectors FAR away from each other or physically separated by some feature of the enclosure?
- Busbars and front-facing terminals: size constraints mean that at least 6 separate jumper busbars would have to be used; this does not only make the installation complex but raise the cost above budget.
- Screw terminals and wires: takes much more space and effort to install. Cannot be reasonably protected from miswiring.
- Backplane: requires extra manufacturing plus still some kind of connectors. Trimming to length is not as clean and foolproof as with busbars.
- Board edge connectors: anything rated for mains voltage is way out of the project's budget so I have not explored this possibility any further.

Thanks in advance for sharing your experience.

Comment: Would you post any drawings, pictures, datasheets?

Comment: @jay Regarding which parts of the question?

Comment: Show a drawing of a "modular device" or link to its data sheet if available @KrálikBarnabás

Comment: Králik , IMO, Focused questions get better answer. Consensus of opinion on general topics often gets TLTR or TBTR,feeling. People drops it before the first paragraph ends. Readers are looking for their own interest. You often find experts "enjoy" giving answers and feedback-s to seemingly very low technical subjects, as much as technically challenging ones. It is like a college essay. Your best interest may not get the most attention. If you poll the "new Questions" on this site, interesting questions get answered immediately, the rest stays in the queue until caught by someone with time.

Comment: 6A is not low current and 250V, 50Hz adjacent to digital logic with out isolation seems dangerous.  How many pins do you need and what are their functions?  How many interconnections?

Comment: @jay I know, but this is the most focus I have regarding the problem; I'm quite lost as I have not been able to find best practices after many hours of reading and googling. I also don't have much experience in using stack exchange. What would you recommend? For example, asking specifically about making pin-and-socket connections safe?

Comment: @KrálikBarnabás, probably I need to read the post more attentively.

Comment: @KrálikBarnabás I read a little more, still cannot get the picture in my mind. My fault..

Comment: Relevant information should be added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> next to each other

I take that to mean "coplanar".
[image]

If so, consider unshrouded board-to-board right-angle PCB headers. They are cheap and installing them on a PCB is easy.

If it helps, consider using only female headers. Then, uses a male-male interposer between adjacent PCB assemblies.

[image]

I don't like it one bit that you plan to run 240 Vac this way, not one bit.

But, if you really must:

Use many more circuits than you need, and leave sections of unused pins as a buffer between the low voltage and high voltage circuits, and between the two AC power lines. The unused pins increase the creepage distance. Also, conformally coat the boards to prevent issues with leakage through moisture.

Comment: I wouldn't want mains on that sort of connector, doubts that's up to code anywhere.

Comment: Yes, this is the rough idea and the words that I've been looking for. 
I will of course use conformal coating. 
The 3,96 mm spaced, 1,1 mm wide pins should provide ample creepage distance already, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Mat I also have doubts about using regular 0.1" headers as they are not rated to anywhere near my specs.

However, I have been unable to locate a standard that specifically deals with this question; could you please give me some pointers?

Comment: @KrálikBarnabás: I don't have any pointers but regardless of standards/norms and rating, there is no protection at all from inserting this sort of header one slot to the left/right which could be disastrous with high voltages. Mains pins would also be unshrouded while live when you insert/remove the connector.

Comment: @Mat I see, this is true! However, this would not simply be a board-to-board connection, but one between plastic-encased devices. Completely exposed pins would never be live, only ones that are being inserted/removed. I believe this is reasonable risk (after all, screws on. e.g. ciruit breakers are usually live as well), but I'm not sure what codes say about this.

Comment: I really have ethical issues with that statement.  What you appear to consider to be reasonable will probably get someone killed.

Comment: A product must not be operated in this way. If the nominal voltage for AC voltage is less than 25 V or for DC voltage less than 60 V, this type of connection can be acceptable.